# Test type of input by React Testing Library - text or password?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I want test the type of input ("text or password") but I don't know how to make it with React Testing Library.

```html
   <OutlinedInput
      className={classes1.ltrInput}
      id='outlined-adornment-password'
      type={showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
      name='password'
      inputProps={{ "data-testid" : "password-input" }}
     />
```

Comment: Are you using https://testing-library.com/docs/ecosystem-jest-dom/? That has matchers for attributes.

Comment: please provide us with more information, this kind of question has no right answer because don't have enought data.

Answer (score 5):

```
expect(screen.getByRole('textBox')).toHaveAttribute('type', 'password');
```

Highly suggested to use getByRole.

https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library

Comment: This likely won't work because `input[type="password"]` has no implicit role. See discussion: https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/issues/567.